# How to find a fixed strings with grep?

Tags: shell-script, grep

How to find a fixed strings with `grep` if the required output is not shown with `grep -F`? For example:

```
egrep -r 'string1|string2|string3' /var/www/http
```

with this what should we use?

Comment: What output with which input do you expect?

Comment: Are you just trying to find three different strings?

Comment: i expect the oputput of three strings but if anything like hash(#) present in the starting and ending of the string then is shows nothing otherwise the output will be those three strings

Comment: Please show some sample input and desired output.

Comment: path="/home/local/abc"
grep -E 'Allow from 8.8.2.5|Allow from 192.3.0.4|DenyAll'* $path

if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
      echo `hostname`
      echo "ftp lock (not accessable outside)"

exit 0
else
     echo `hostname`
     echo "ftp unlock ( accessable from  outside)"
exit 1
fi

Comment: What's your intention with the `*` at the end of the patterns.  Are you looking for fixed strings or not?

Comment: yes i am looking for fixed string from a whole file

Comment: i want that the grep command not show me commented string

Answer (score 10):

Either use `grep -E` (the modern form for `egrep`) so `|` be treated as an extended regular expression *alternation* operator, but then you'd need to escape every other regular expression operator (like `.`, `?`, `*`, `^`, `$`, `\`, `[`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`) in your *fixed strings*.

Or use `-F` and pass the strings one per line or with several `-e`s:

```
grep -Fe string1 -e string2 -e string3
```

Or:

```
grep -F 'string1
string2
string3'
```

Add the `-x` option if those fixed strings have to make up the entire matched line (as opposed to be found anywhere *within* the line without it). Most `grep` implementations also have a `-w` option for *word* match where for instance, `string1` would match inside `foo string1-2`, but not inside `foostring12`.

For your specific example in comments, that would be:

```
grep -wE 'Allow from (8\.8\.2\.5|192\.3\.0\.4)|DenyAll'
```

Or:

```
grep -we 'Allow from 8.8.2.5' -e 'Allow from 192.3.0.4' -e 'DenyAll'
```

You'd want either `-w` or `-x` (assuming that's the whole lines, not even spaces around) here as otherwise it would also match on lines like `Allow from 8.8.2.51`.

You can also write it:

```
grep -xE '[[:space:]]*(Allow from (8\.8\.2\.5|192\.3\.0\.4)|DenyAll)[[:space:]]*'
```

To match on the full line (`-x`) but allowing leading and trailing spacing characters (here using `[[:space:]]` instead of `[[:blank:]]` to also allow the CR characters found at the end of lines coming from the MS-DOS world).

To look for those fixed strings anywhere in the line but not inside comments, you'd need to ensure that the part of the line leading to those fixed strings doesn't contain `#` characters. So something like:

```
grep -wE '^[^#]*(Allow from (8\.8\.2\.5|192\.3\.0\.4)|DenyAll)'
```

Note that the `-w` there doesn't apply to `Allow` as it applies to the whole matched string. So it would match on `GAllow from` for instance. Some `grep` implementations support `\<`, `\>` to match *word boundaries* explicitly (also known as `\b` in some):

```
grep -E '^[^#]*\<(Allow from (8\.8\.2\.5|192\.3\.0\.4)|DenyAll)\>'
```

Also note that in `apache2`, configuration directives are case insensitive and any number of blanks are allowed between words. Also, I suspect you meant `Deny from all` instead of `DenyAll`, so maybe you'd want:

```
grep -iE '^[^#]*\<(allow[[:blank:]]+from[[:blank:]]+(8\.8\.2\.5|192\.3\.0\.4)|deny[[:blank:]]+from[[:blank:]]+all)\>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that

```
grep -F -r 'string1|string2|string3' /var/www/http
```

would look for the literal string `string1|string2|string3` in the files.  Note, since you are looking for fixed strings, there is no reason to use `egrep` (or `grep -E`).

What you could do is to use

```
printf '%s\n' 'string1' 'string2' 'string3' | grep -f /dev/stdin -F -r /var/www/http
```

This would make `grep` read the fixed strings to match against from standard input (provided by `printf`) and use them to get all lines that matched them in any file under the given directory.

Anything that generates a text document with the patterns on separate lines may replace the `printf` above, including a simple text file (which could be read directly by `grep -f textfile -F ...`).

---

Example from your comments:

Look for any of the strings `Allow from 8.8.2.5`, `Allow from 192.3.0.4` and `DenyAll` in the files in `$dirpath`:

```
printf '%s\n' 'Allow from 8.8.2.5' 'Allow from 192.3.0.4' 'DenyAll' |
grep -f /dev/stdin -F -r "$dirpath"
```

Comment: it is not working..Is there any alternative way to do this ?

Comment: @Gurpreetkaur To be able to debug your issue, I would need to know what the exact command you tried and what the result was (including error messages etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The pipes `|` need to be escaped `\|` like so:

```
grep 'string1\|string2\|string3\' /var/www/http
```

Comment: The issue is that if one string contains a special character such as `*`, this will not work without escaping that/those characters. You would have to insert an extra step to escape all special characters in the strings.

Comment: Note that `\|` is a GNU extension, unspecified per POSIX, not supported by all `grep`  implementations.